# Changing linux user password from Golang not working

Tags: linux, passwords, go

I need a one-liner from inside a go routine to change a user's password in linux.

The command that WORKS from the command line:

```
      echo 'pgc:password' | sudo chpasswd  //"pgc" is the username and "password" 
                                           // is the password I'm changing it to.
```

But this doesn't work from  my Go program. I have tried substituting other one-liner commands, such as:
drm file.txt, touch file.txt, etc.

And those all work.

The Go program is in a package inside a big project, but I am now just attempting to run it directly from the command line (not used as a function, but a standalone .go file).

My Code:

```
    //I have tried changing back and forth between the package that changesystempassword.go is in 
    // and main, but that has no effect

    package main //one-liners DON'T WORK if package is the package this go file is in

    import (
        "fmt"
        "os/exec"
        //"time"
    )

    func main() {
        err := exec.Command("echo", "'pgc:password'", "|", "sudo", "chpasswd).Run()

        //time.sleep(time.Second) - tried adding a sleep so it would have time?

        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Password change unsuccessful"
        } else {
            fmt.Println("Password change successful")
        }
    }
```

The result when the program is run (./changesystempassword from the command line) is that the command line shows "Password change successful". But guess what. It hasn't changed. I have found a few similar examples online and on Stack Exchange, but I am using the solutions I found there and it isn't working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Command) says "execute the named program with the given arguments". There even is a specific paragraph:

> Unlike the "system" library call from C and other languages, the os/exec package intentionally does not invoke the system shell and does not expand any glob patterns or handle other expansions, pipelines, or redirections typically done by shells.

So the code in the question executes `echo` with the arguments `'pgc:password'`, `|`, `sudo`, and `chpasswd`. This is successful as `echo` can totally print those four strings.

The solution is to start `chpasswd` directly and write to its standard input. This is a minimal example:

```
func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("chpasswd")
    stdin, err := cmd.StdinPipe()
    io.WriteString(stdin, "pgc:password")
}
```

I advise to adjust the code shown in the official [example](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd.StdinPipe) for safe code with error-checking.

You can also use `sudo chpasswd` instead of `chpasswd`. Keep in mind that `sudo` will not be able to ask for a password in this scenario. One workaround is configuring sudoers with NOPASSWD where appropriate.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have tried for hours to make sense of this, but I'm not getting it. I can't figure out what you mean by "start chpasswd directly". The chpasswd command doesn't work on the command line without the use of "echo". I have tried to incorporate my command into the example you linked to, but I am failing to understand some basic concept in here.

Comment: You probably do not know about the [standard streams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams). In an interactive shell, the pipe operator `|` takes the output (stdout) of the left program and feeds it into the input (stdin) of the right program. I added a minimal, untested example to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Hermann. My misunderstanding was a little more nuanced. I spent a long time trying to get the example you led me to to work. It wasn't until a coworker suggested that I threw a \n after the argument passed to the command that it finally worked.

So the code that worked (basically that Stdin example with a small change):

```
cmd := exec.Command("sudo", "chpasswd")
stdin, err := cmd.StdinPipe()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

go func() {
    defer stdin.Close()
    io.WriteString(stdin, "pgc:password\n")
}()

out, err := cmd.CombinedOutput()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```